# YII ACL beforeFind BeforeSave Access controll

Tags: php, security, frameworks, access-control, yii2

Currently I'm implementing my own ACL system.
For restricting database actions I rewrote the `beforeSave` **function** from the `ActiveRecord` **class**.

I'm implementing my function as the default model class.

```
class Event extends ACL
{

...

}
```

So far so good. In my database I have a privilege table where I store user,group,creator or self roles which relate to actions on specific table's. I use the standard **RBAC** from **yii** for page restriction based on **user-level** so I don't have to check all privileges on each page load. The ACL behavior is for database related purposes only. Like if a user would like to see post/someid/view and he has no rights for that specific post access is not granted.

By example  Role: Group  Who: 4  Action: insert  Table: Event

Now group with id 4 has privileges to insert into the event table. That part works fine, now I want to be able to restrict certain users from searching table's in my database. Same if 'role' would be 'user'. In the documentation I can't find something like beforeFind.

Does somebody know where I can hack in to the system and control the let's call it ***beforeFind*** function?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to derive your `ActiveRecord`-based classes from your own class instead of the `framework\db`-one. If you do that then you can add the checks wherever/however you want.

In theory you should be able to get away with just overriding the `find()`-function and forbid it from returning an `ActiveQuery` instance. Unfortunately the framework functions themselves don't check if they got an instance and will call methods on it anyway. So expect problems there.

Practically speaking, you'll end up having to override the rest as well (line findOne etc). That still leaves people with the possibility to either use the default ActiveRecord or the db connection itself.

To be honest I can't see a single use for trying to add security this low. And I'm fairly sure that whatever you'll need to do to get this "safe", it will introduce hell for the person having to maintain it.